# How to increase width of body with respect to adding elements from database?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to increase the width of body of html page with respect to multiple div(having images) retrieve from database.Here is code:

**HTML**

```
<div class = "mainDiv">
   <div id = "filer" class = "filterPanel">
   </div>
   <div id="imgPanel" class="imgPanelDiv">
        <ul id ="imgPanelUi">
            <?php require_once './getData.php';?>
        </ul>HTML
   </div>
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .mainDiv{
        position: relative;
    }
.filterPanel{
    width: 20%;
    height: 600px;
    padding: 40px 0 10px 0;
    position: relative;
}
.imgPanelDiv{
    width:80%;
    position: absolute;
    top : 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

I also set `<div class="imagePanelDiv" style = "float : left"`> but its look strange.

**Note**

With the above code the body having width until filterDiv(set 600px).After this the body is not available and all the other images are out of bound. I want that body width is increase so that all images( in "imgPanel" class) are display on the body.

Need help?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
min-width: 600px;
width: auto
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `position:absolute;` in you imgPanelDiv

Comment: imgPanelDiv override with filterPanel.